# Google autocomplete js script is not working

Tags: google-maps, web

I have a website for appointment booking. I want to put google maps autocomplete city option with the search option. Here is the script I using (along with my api)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function activatePlacesSearch(){
        var input document.getElementById('city');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqt53eRNuhV9550UnBfs-8sZbnMs55lac=places&callback=activatePlacesSearch"></script>
```

The id of my input filed is *city*. But after placing this script it does not suggest any autofill option.

Comment: You aren't including the places library correctly in the URL for the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you load the script above, which doesn't know anything about the google.maps API. Then after executing the script you load google.maps API.

Try loading google.maps API first and see if that helps yourself.